# What’s new with asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can someone take me through what’s new with asp.net mvc3?

Comment: There's a summary of what's new in the Release Notes here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6&displaylang=en

Comment: Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#overview and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

Comment: This is a bi-monthly question.  Its too bad the search never finds it.

Comment: I would say the one big improvement is the introduction of the Razor View Engine. (Simply, it rocks!)

Comment: come on dude. go to google, subscribe to rss feeds, go to asp.net, etc - it's not hard!

Comment: @jfar: then perhaps he shouldn't be so downvoted? Upvoted, also due to the fact that google led me HERE, and it was helpful.

Answer (score 7):

A few additional features in ASP.NET MVC 3 are

1. Razor view engine
2. Improved model validation with unobtrusive JavaScript and jQuery support. Including new
3. remote validation amoungst others
4. Partial page output caching.
5. Dependency Injection Improvements, new [IDependencyResolver](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html)

A more indepth list can be found on the [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) site and from [Scott Guthrie's annoucement](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx)

Comment: Can you tell something about here **Improved model validation with unobtrusive JavaScript and jQuery support. Including new** ?

Comment: @PankajGarg checkout : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336430/what-exactly-is-improved-in-mvc3-pertaining-to-validation