# What exactly is improved in MVC3 pertaining to validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

In [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) - Improved model validation with unobtrusive JavaScript and jQuery support.

I think, [unobtrusive-validation](/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-validation) is already present in [asp.net-mvc-2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-2)

Question : What exactly is improved in MVC3 pertaining to client validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think, unobtrusive-validation is already present in asp.net-mvc-2

Ah no, it wasn't.

> Question : What exactly is improved in MVC3 pertaining to client validation?

The Ajax.* helpers are now using HTML5 data-* attributes which are interpreted by the jquery unobtrusive validation scripts. In ASP.NET MVC 2 the Ajax.* helpers were polluting the HTML with javascript calling to the absolute legacy `Microsoft*.js` scripts.

Comment: So difference is only in regard to scripts i.e. `Microsoft*.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` ?

Comment: Not only, it's also the Ajax.* helpers and their output.

Comment: What do you mean when you said **and their output.** ?

Comment: `Ajax.*` helpers spit HTML at the end of the day. In ASP.NET MVC 2 this HTML is polluted with javascript. In ASP.NET MVC 3 there's no javascript in their output, only HTML5 `data-*` attributes which are used by the unobtrusive validation library.

Comment: I am sorry for asking u over and over again. But green card is sure urs in this thread. Can you please tell about ** In ASP.NET MVC 2 this HTML is polluted with javascript**

Comment: For example the anchor that the Ajax.ActionLink helper generates in ASP.NET MVC 2 contains an `onclick` event handler which contains javascript. So you have mixed HTML and javascript which is bad. Look it for yourself and you will see the difference.

Comment: @SMC , What Darin has explained u is difference between obtrusive and unobtrusive ...